# How to pull a particular tag onto a Server

Tags: mercurial, pull

I have a tag created on mercurial on my Dev server called "today". I would like to update thee files on th Test server to the tag level "today". Can someone tell me how do I do that?

Is it going to be **hg pull origin "today"**

Answer (score 1):

You're missing some basics.  `hg pull` will never update local files (unless you use `-u` but don't do that).  So first you need to get the changeset that defines the tag onto the server:

```
hg pull origin
```

That pulls over all the changesets but doesn't update any files.  Then if you want *all* the files on the server to match those of the `today` tag you do:

```
hg update today
```

That makes sure all the files look like they do at the `today` tag.  That command does no network activity at all -- it's just getting files out of the local repository you filled up using `pull`.

If you really, really want to only update those 3 files you'd do:

```
hg update --rev file1 pathto/file2 other/path/to/file3
```

In general though you should try find a workflow where all the files in your server's working directory are at the same revision.  Files checked out at different revisions in the same repository was a svn sort of thing -- git and hg don't generally work that way.